# How to center a marker in a leaflet makers cluster spiderfy?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

[image: Map]

The icon is displayed in the bottom cornor of blue shape. How can I align it in the center? It is not just one shape to control it via CSS. I have many shapes and each looking different.

The cluster is created using the following code:

```
this.stationMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup({
  iconCreateFunction: function (cluster) {
    const icons = [], temps = [];
    const markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();

    for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      if (markers[i]['Tavg']) temps.push((markers[i]['Tavg']));
      if (markers[i]['Icon']) icons.push((markers[i]['Icon']));
    }

    return L.divIcon({
      html: `<img src=\'./assets/images/icons-png/${icons.length > 0 ? math.mode(icons)[0] : ''}.png\'
              width="50px"/>
             <span>${(math.sum(temps) / temps.length).toFixed(1) + '°C'}</span>`,
    });
  },
});
```

And the icons are created:

```
for (const d of this.data) {
  const icon = new L.DivIcon({
    html: `<img src='./assets/images/icons-png/${d.icon}.png' width="50px"/>
              <span>${d.Temp + '°C'}</span>`,
  });

  const marker = L.marker([d.Latitude, d.Longitude], {icon});
  marker['Tavg'] = d.Temp;
  marker['Icon'] = d.icon;

  this.stationMarkers.addLayer(marker);

  latitudes.push(d.Latitude);
  longitudes.push(d.Longitude);
}
```

Package: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster

Example: https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld-maxzoom.388.html

Comment: Not sure If I understood correct the issue but in case you want to place a marker in the center of a polygon you can do it using `polygon.getBounds().getCenter();`. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ajsgrwcx/)

Comment: @kboul you got me right. The polygon is created by leaflet markers cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `iconAnchor: [25, 25]` fixed it.

```
return L.divIcon({
  html: `<img src=\'./assets/images/icons-png/${icons.length > 0 ? math.mode(icons)[0] : ''}.png\'
          width="50px"/>
         <span>${(math.sum(temps) / temps.length).toFixed(1) + '°C'}</span>`,
  iconAnchor: [25, 25],
});
```

It is not always in the center but at least looking better than what I had before.

The ideal solution would be as @kboul suggested to get the polygon center and place the icon there, but not sure how to do this, since leaflet markers cluster creates polygons.